# How to create database in My mysql version and OS is 5.5.47.0 ubuntu 0.14.04.1 for entering chinese data

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

My mysql version and OS is 5.5.47.0 ubuntu 0.14.04.1 i need to add Chinese charector to my database table from a java spring mvc application how can i create table for that , i have tried using Character Set utf8mb4    and Collation utft8mb4_unicode_ci  ,   Character Set utf8  and Collation utft8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

-> need to update local mysql config ie, my.cnf

-> paste

character-set-server = utf8mb4
   collation-server = utf8mb4 unicode ci

right under [mysqId]